# Azure Stream Analytics Query - get last request for all device

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have IoT Hub, it collects messages from many devices. Data from IoT Hub are sent to stream analytics, and now I would like to stream analytics, display a list of all devices along with the last request. That is, a table in which there are eg 10 devices and with each device its last request.

My actual code:

```
SELECT
       deviceId,
       param1 as humidity,
       param2 as temperature,
       datetime as data
FROM hubMessage 
GROUP By deviceId, data,temperature,humidity, 
TumblingWindow(minute,5)
```

Ont this query i have error on deviceId:

```
GROUP BY with no aggregate expressions is not supported.
```

I dont'h have any idea, how resolve my problem with not supported expression and change last request for all device ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GROUP BY with no aggregate expressions is not supported.

According to this error message,you need to use group by with aggregate expression.All aggregate expressions supported by ASA are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/aggregate-functions-azure-stream-analytics).

If you want to get the latest request,i think the [TopOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/topone-azure-stream-analytics) is suitable for you.

[image]

If you want to select all the data match the filter,maybe you could use [COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/count-azure-stream-analytics) with group by.

Comment: Hi :) I solved my problem, when use TopOne in my query. I mark your answer as a solution to the problem, because with TopOne I solved it myself.

Comment: @PawelC That's great.